# Cannot sign into Heroku

Tags: heroku

Whenever I try logging into the Heroku dashboard I would get redirected back to the login screen without any error, but checking the Network logs results in a "303 See Other" redirect for some reason. Why could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your password, it should solve it.